# How to use databinding with livedata provided by ROOM Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to data bind my XML layout directly with the live data provided by ROOM database. But I see that the query is done infinitely and no value is received in the XML.

Here is my code structure.

My ROOM API in the class `DataDao`

```
getMyData(): LiveData<Model?>
```

My XML View

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/some_card_view"
    style="@styles/CardStyle"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.dataProvider.getMyData()!=null ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

Here I am just trying to display this card if the data provided by room is not null. Display otherwise. But in the logs I see that it's constantly querying the database and I can see the log printed in the `dataProvider` class's method.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any other way of handling livedata from room directly in XML databinding?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object in your viewModel:

```
val myData : LiveData<Model?> = dataProvider.getMyData()
```

next, you can map it to the desired condition field

```
val canShowSomeCardView = Transformations.map(myData) {
       it != null
}
```

So now you have the bool to operate within your xml.
I would suggest to create a binding adapter for such things:

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("bindVisibleGone")
fun bindVisibleInvisible(view: View, isVisible: Boolean?) {
      view.visibility = if (isVisible == true) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

So now in your xml:

```
app:bindVisibleGone="@{viewModel.canShowSomeCardView}"
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why the original author's code caused "infinite loop"? It seems I have a similar type of problem (trying to query `@{repository.getSmth(item)}` from recycler view's data-binding)